# OPENSSL: What is the difference of enc command and cms' enc command?

Tags: encryption, openssl, padding, cms

I found something strange while checking the inside of the envelope data.

I had plain text "plaintextplant" - length is $15$ (include `lf(0x0A`))`. I made a .ber file that is encrypted by AES256 and encoded DER via:

> openssl cms -encrypt -in plain -aes256 -recip certificate.pem -outform DER -out enveloped-data.ber

Then, I checked the encrypted data through berReader.
I thought that the encrypted data is 16 bytes long because the length of the plain text is $15$.
However, the length of the result is $32$ bytes.

[image]

So, I typed:

> openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in plain -out enc -k 123
> ,for get a encrypted data.

Then, I checked the length of encrypted data is $16$ bytes in output data.

I give you pictures of the result:

[image]

Why is the size of the cms encrypted data 32 bytes?

Plus, I attach the picture that the length of the plain text is 13 bytes.
Its encrypted data size is 16bytes.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openssl cms -encrypt/sign` by default applies SMIME canonicalization -- even when the output format isn't SMIME. This changes LF to CRLF making the data 16 bytes, padded to 32. To see this look at

```
 openssl cms -decrypt -in yourcmsder -inform der -recip cert -inkey privkey | od -tx1
```

To prevent this, add `-binary` on the encrypt. See the man page on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/cms.html).

Also, as kelalaka says, `enc -k` (and also `-kfile -pass` or no option which prompts) does password-based encryption that derives the key and IV from the password and salt (which is normally random but can be specified with `-S` or suppressed with `-nosalt`). You can get a result closer to the data in `cms -encrypt`, but without the canonicalization, with something like

```
openssl enc -aes-cbc-256 -in plain -K (hexupto64) -iv (hexupto32) -out encrypted
# note uppercase K not lowercase k
# key,iv are padded if needed so just 00 for each is okay for test
```

This doesn't do the key derivation, so it doesn't use salt, and thus doesn't store the salt in the encrypted output.

Answer (score 1):

AES is a block cipher and needs a proper [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) like CBC, CTR, and so on.

While the streaming modes like CFB, OFB, and CTR don't require padding the CBC and ECB mode of operations requires padding.

In CBC mode the usual padding is the [PKCS#7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2315#section-10.3) padding. For CBC encryption the message is divided into 128-bit blocks and the padding is applied into the last block. There can be two cases;

1. The message has missed some bytes; in this case, let $n$ is the number of missing bytes, then the number $n$ is added $n$ times as a byte.

   ```
   [Message Bytes    ][01]       // 1 Byte is missing
   [Message Bytes  ][0202]       // 2 Bytes are missing 
   [Message Bytes][030303]       // 3 Bytes are missing
   ....
   [MB][0F0F0F...0F0F0F0F]       // 15 Bytes are missing
   ```
2. The message is multiple of 16-byte, this means that the last block is full. In this case, to distinguish this case from the first case we add a new block full of `10`s. Therefore, we can have the reverse of the padding. One can see the reason as to what if the last block has `01` as the last byte. Is it padding or not? So adding `01` removes this ambiguity.

The above can explain why a message becomes a multiple of 16 bytes after proper CBC encryption.

In the case of the question, 15 bytes can become 16 bytes by adding `01` as the last byte. What about the remaining 16-bytes?

CBC mode of operation needs a 16-byte **random** and **unpredictable** Initialization Vector (**IV**) to achieve Ind-CPA security.

IV is one of the requirements for the decryption of the first block other than the key ( key, IV, and $C_0$ is required);

$$P_0 = \operatorname{AES-DEC}(key,C_0) \oplus IV$$

Therefore the IV must be added/transferred, too. In the usual practice, the IV is appended to ciphertext.

---

What if IV is not stored/transferred? Well, you will lose only the first block of the message, the rest can be decrypted properly since;

$$P_i = \operatorname{AES-DEC}(key,C_i) \oplus C_{i-1}, \quad i \geq 1$$

---

**CMS**

The [CMS requires](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3565#section-4.1)

> The AlgorithmIdentifier parameters field MUST be present, and the
> parameters field MUST contain a AES-IV:
>
> ```
>   AES-IV ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(16))
> ```

The IV is stored in the `AlgorithmIdentifier` field, not in the `encryptedContent` As [Dave](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/97894/18298) wroted it is `-binary` issue.

---

- OpenSSL option `-k`

  The IV and Key are derived from the key derivation method by using the user's password and the 8-byte random salt. The IV is not prepended.

  OpenSSL first outputs the magic word `Salted__` then 8-byte salt then the ciphertext into the file. Now the output size is your magic size + salt size + ciphertext-size

Comment: Shoot me if I'm wrong about CMS..

Comment: I don't think shooting is justified, but you are wrong; as stated in the first two lines of your quote, the IV is in the parameters part of the AlgorithmIdentifier, not appended (or prepended) to the ciphertext in encryptedContent.

Comment: I see, I've little update to remove the incorrect leading part. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to you, I learned about AES-IV field in CMS.

Comment: FYI, once you get 15 reputations you can upvote, too. in SO, upvote if the answer is helpful to you, accept if solves the problem.